# How to resolve git pull error: timer thread did not terminate timely?

Tags: git, git-push

I recently renamed by mistake a 2GB file locally and when I did `commit` and `push`, to promote new changes to other files, the file was removed from the repository. Hence I had to rename and `add` it again. 
But when I did again `commit` and `push` in order to restore the lost file I got following error message:

> error: timer thread did not terminate timely

Bellow you can see the whole message:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 871.90 MiB | 482.00 KiB/s, done.
error: timer thread did not terminate timely
Total 5 (delta 1), reused 3 (delta 0)
To x:/Archivos Python/EPPTRA2.git/
   b3c7708..8a86cd7  master -> master
```

How can I get push to work properly?

Otherwise, which would be the best way to restore the file removed from repository? Taking into account that I would like to retain the changes to other files but recovering the file I removed.

I thought about doing `git push -f origin <sha_of_previous_commit>:master` but not sure about it being the best solution.

Comment: It appears that the push did work although an error was shown. As the pull from another machine (after the two commits from my local machine) didn't remove the file.

Comment: If you reset HEAD to previous commit  you should able to see your file which you changed in current commit however it was before